# How to create a graph using yahoo Api in Android Studio?

Tags: java, graph, yahoo-api

How can we create a graph using yahoo finance stock Api in android studio. We can display the other metrics but we are unsure on how to code for the graph.

Do we need a graph view Or custom view for the graph? 
How can we code for a live graph for each stock

Any guidance or help will be much appreciated :)

Thank you